# Preprocess strings file during Xcode build

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, preprocessor

I know there's a way to preprocess my info.plist file, but is there a similar way to process strings files inside my Settings.bundle?

My problem: I have an iPhone app and I want the the user to know about the currently installed version. I do this by displaying it in the apps settings. Now every time i change the bundle version in my info.plist i also have to change the version in the `Root.strings` in the  `Settings.bundle`. I could run a script action that updates it, but it would be nice to use the preprocessor since I could do even more fun things with it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The preprocessor XCode runs on all string-files is copystrings. It resides in /Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/CoreBuildTasks.xcplugin/Contents/Resources. It's a simple ruby script, but it dosen't support any preprocessing/macro-expansion.

You could of cause extend the script, but then you would be easier off with a different script running in a run script build phase, as you already suggested.

Answer (score -1):

Make it so that your view asks the bundle and then directly queries the `Info.plist` file and extracts the `CFBundleVersion` (or the appropriate key you wish to extract) The version should never need to be stored in a `.strings` file. Next all you need to do is have a format string to prepare it for display. One useful thing if you care about localization is to instead have a localized string in your `.strings` labeled something like `"%@<CFBundleVersion format string>" = "Version: %@";` Then you get a quick visual indicator if your localizers have done their jobs in all languages.

```
MyInfoView *infoView = /*...*/;
NSString *version = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
infoView.versionLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"%@<CFBundleVersion format string>",nil), version];
```

Comment: If the string is going to be present in the Settings.app then the version needs to be in a strings file. Please reread my question.